# How to extract adobe xd source file from published prototype link?

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

I have adobe xd prototype link I want to extract source project from that link, I don't have saved that file anywhere on cloud. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it's saved locally, you can open the file, locate the "Share" button at the top right corner, click the button, click "share for review", and hit "create link". You will be provided a prototype URL for your document

Comment: The problem is, I don't have xd file. I was working with a freelancer he gave me the prototype link only I want to extract its source file

Comment: There is no functionality that allows you to extract the source file from the prototype link